# Return true/false value of a javascript function and then do stuff based on that

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm building a contact form and I need help with the jQuery validator.

```
function contactform() {
    $("form #submit").on("click", function() {
        $("form input").removeClass("error");
        validator();
        // 3rd action goes here
    });
});
```

`validator()` checks to see if any input is left empty, and if so it adds an error class to it:

```
function validator() {
    $("form input").each(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value.length <= 0) {
            $(this).addClass("error");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Now, for the 3rd action in `contactform()` I want to say that if `validator() = true` (i.e. there no inputs that are empty), then continue on to the next code.

I can't seem to return the value of `validator()`. Does anybody know the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is another solution using `filter` method:

```
function validator() {
    return $("form input").filter(function() {
        return $.trim(this.value).length == 0;
    }).addClass("error").length == 0;
});

function contactform() {
    ...
    if (validator()) {
        // it's OK
    } else {
        // there are errors
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Awesomely updated with [the help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789069/return-true-false-value-of-a-javascript-function-and-then-do-stuff-based-on-that/10789118#comment14033422_10789118) of @am_not_i_am. Thanks!

Comment: If you string the `.addClass("error")` to the end of the `.filter`, then you could just do `return $.trim($(this).value()).length == 0` inside.

Comment: ...but +1 'cause I like the `.filter` approach.

Comment: +1 as I too like the `filter()` function, if only there where one more equal thingy when checking for zero ?

Comment: @adeneo Do you mean using `===`?

Comment: I'm a little out of my depth with this one, but thanks anyway. I'm not going to use this simply because I am lost and have no idea what's going on!

Comment: @muppethead `filter` method outputs only that `input` elements which contain nothing as a `value`. To that elements `addClass` adds class `"error"`. Function `validator` returns `true` *only* if number of empty `input` elements equals `0`. Don't you find it easy to understand?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but you underestimate my ignorance! I understand the logic behind your `filter` method, I'm just lost on syntax. Why is it you put `return` before $("form input"). And why is there a return inside the filter function? Why is there .length==0 after `addClass`? Also, why does `contactform()` have ellipses? I am grateful for your help here, but I hope you can see I am severely out of my depth.

Comment: @muppethead: VisioN showed a nice example of how it would be written in its most terse form. To understand it, you can break it apart a bit, like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/wgYPJ/). Ultimately you're returning the result of comparing the `.length` of the filtered set to `0`. It may be easier to comprehend if you put the `0` as the left hand operator to `===`, so `return 0 === $("form input").filter(...).length`.

Answer (score 4):

```
function validator() {
    var result = true;
    $("form input").removeClass("error");
    $('form input').each(function() {
           if(!$.trim(this.value)) {
             $(this).addClass('.error');
             result = false;  
           }
     });
    return result;
}


function contactform() {
    $("form #submit").on("click", function() {
        if(validator()) { // pass the validation

        } else { // fail validation

        }
        // 3rd action goes here
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes he was really fast! Any reason the trim method is superior to .val() method? Also, does `if (value)` pretty much mean "if value is nothing" ? In your 2nd validator function, when does it execute? I have the submit action calling validator() to run - I can't seem to figure it out on yours.

Comment: Hmm... Your `.filter()` isn't doing any filtering. Or more accurately, it's filtering the set down to nothing every time, but doing nothing with the result. The way it is, it's really no different than an `.each()`.

Comment: @thecodeparadox Don't delete it. Just remove the filter and go back to how you initially helped me. I was busy examining it and you changed it all of a sudden.

Comment: @thecodeparadox There is no need in deletion. Your variant with `each` was rather workable.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you seem to encounter is that you have a nested function and closure, which prevents you from returning the value directly.

Something like that should do the trick:

```
function validator() {
    var result=true;
    $("form input").each(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value.length <= 0) {
            $(this).addClass("error");
            result = false;
        }
    });
    return result;
});
```

Comment: Your answer is the closest to mine and hence the only one here that I understand, so thanks for that.